# Como introduzco los datos en la matriz a traves de un formulario?

Tags: php

El ejercicio es introducir los datos en una matriz 4x4 de array bidimiensionales e imprimirla como matriz.
Yo hago la matriz pero meterle los datos por formulario lo unico que se me ocurre es crear 14 variables con campos y meterlas en los arrays.

```
echo "<h1> matriz de 4x4 </h1>";

    $matriz = array(
        array(2, 3, 50, 6),
        array(3, 8, 15, 5),
        array(4, 66, 0, 82),
        array(6, 70, 20, 4),
    );

    foreach ($matriz as $fila) {
        foreach ($fila $numero) {
            echo " $numero";
        }

        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: ¿Quieres que desde php se rellene la matriz o que desde la matriz se rellene php?

Comment: Creo que `foreach ($fila $numero) {` debería ser `foreach ($fila as $numero) {`

Comment: quiero un formulario que rellene la matriz ara imprimirla luego. Osea tu rellena el formulario y al darle al sumit imprime la matriz, pero tiene que ser atraves de array bidimensionales no vale oner los numeros y listo

Comment: que opiniones?es una cosa concreta como meter datos de un formulario en un array

Comment: Es demasiado amplia, no es un problema concreto, estas pidiendo que otros piensen por vos como hacer algo y ese algo esta sujeto a múltiples factores

Comment: Agregué una forma más facil usando un `array[]` en el formulario en vez de diferentes `name` para cada `input`.

Answer (score 1):

### Generando propiedades dinámicamente

Un método puede ser creando *iterativamente* las propiedades "`name`" en los `<input...>` del formulario, y luego que haces `POST` vuelves a recrearlas para recoger los datos. En el código lo vas a entender mejor.

Este es un formulario muy básico, sin arreglos css ni nada de eso, solo la funcionalidad.

```
<?php
$x = 4; // Filas de la matriz
$y = 4; // Columnas
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="l_x" value="<?php echo $x;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="l_y" value="<?php echo $y;?>">
    <?php
    for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++) {
        for($j=0; $j<$y; $j++) {
            echo $i.'-'.$j;
            ?>
            <input type="text" name="idx_<?php echo $i.'-'.$j;?>" size="4" required>
            <?php
        }
        echo '<br /><br />';
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
<?php
```

Esto va a crear cada campo `input` con los siguientes `name="idx_0-0"`, `name="idx_0-1"`... y así sucesivamente. Se envían por `hidden` las dimensiones de la matriz para poder reconstruirla en la función de capturar los datos.

Ahora para capturar los datos con una vez se ha enviado el formulario, con los 2 `for`, por cada iteración se vuelve a crear `$idx = 'idx_0-0'`, `$idx = 'idx_0-1'`... y así sucesivamente. Cada uno de esos `$idx` coinciden con los que se enviaron desde el formulario. Y luego son capturados por `$_POST[$idx];` que los guardará en el `$array` en la posición respectiva.

```
<?php
$x = $_POST['l_x'];
$y = $_POST['l_y'];
$matriz = array();
for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j<$y; $j++) {
        $idx = 'idx_'.$i.'-'.$j;
        $matriz[$i][$j] = $_POST[$idx];
    }
}
print_r($matriz); // El array (matriz) introducido
```

### Otra manera

Otra forma más fácil puede ser enviando los datos del formulario en forma de `array[]`, similar a como se hace con los campos `checkbox`. Nunca lo habia intentado de esa forma con `input text`, probé y funciona.

```
<?php
$x = 4;
$y = 4;
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="l_x" value="<?php echo $x;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="l_y" value="<?php echo $y;?>">
    <?php
    for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++) {
        for($j=0; $j<$y; $j++) {
            echo $i.'-'.$j;
            ?>
            <input type="text" name="data[]" size="4" required>
            <?php
        }
        echo '<br /><br />';
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
<?php
```

Y para recibir los datos

```
<?php
$x = $_POST['l_x'];
$y = $_POST['l_y'];
$values = $_POST['data']; // Array unidimensional
$matriz = array();
$k = 0;
for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j<$y; $j++) {
        $matriz[$i][$j] = $values[$k++];
    }
}
print_r($matriz); // La matriz
```

Notar que `$matriz[$i][$j]` recibe el valor de `$values[$k];` y luego se incrementa, `$k++`, siguiendo las reglas del [Post-Incremento](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: no lo acabo de ver soy mas de Java y php me cuesta mucho, puedes explicarmelo un poco mas

Comment: Creo que no hay forma más fácil de hacerlo @unknow es algo más de html en el formulario, PHP solo está dinamizando los campos `name="alguna-cosa"`. Y la parte de recibir los datos, es casi la misma sintaxis de java.

Comment: 16 campos de formulario con 16 variables y asi relleno cada array de 4 y?¿

Comment: A ver si nos entendemos. Según la pregunta, se te ocurría por cada input en el formulario hacer: `name="var-0-0"`, `name="var-0-1"` y así hasta completar los 16. Luego en la función de capturar pensabas hacer: `$value-0-0=$POST['var-0-0'];` `$value-0-1=$POST['var-0-1'];` ...etc. Y finalmente llenabas el array  `$matriz[0][0] = $value-0-0;` `$matriz[0][1] = $value-0-1` ... hasta `$matriz[3][3] = $value-3-3;`, y listo. Bueno, mi código hace EXACTAMENTE ESO pero de forma dinámica. Yo quise ponerle `idx_xx-xx` al identificador, pero puedes poner como desees.